# Psycopg2 - Eventlet connection hang

Tags: python, psycopg2, eventlet

I have a program which keeps a persistent connection to a postgresql server. Suppose the connection is blocked  due to network issues(can be simulated by bringing down network interface), the process which invoked query using eventlet is getting stuck. This is preventing other eventlets also from executing. Attaching gdb indicated that processes is blocked in psycopg2 C code. I tried postgresql TCP keepalives. But this will also fail if a query is invoked as soon as the connection is lost.

Is there any way to prevent eventlet from getting in to this state ? Is there any way to break eventlet out of this state.

**GDB**

```
#0  0x00002b4e7836be46 in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002b4e835dec4f in ?? () from /usr/pgsql-9.0/lib/libpq.so.5
#2  0x00002b4e835ded50 in ?? () from /usr/pgsql-9.0/lib/libpq.so.5
#3  0x00002b4e835dd28e in PQgetResult () from /usr/pgsql-9.0/lib/libpq.so.5
#4  0x00002b4e833a4284 in psyco_exec_green (conn=0x21f42510, command=<value optimized out>) at psycopg/green.c:195
#5  0x00002b4e833a5387 in pq_execute_command_locked (conn=0x21f42510, 
    query=0x2b4e833b5de8 "BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED", pgres=0x7fff84c38448, error=0x7fff84c38440, 
    tstate=0x7fff84c38438) at psycopg/pqpath.c:342
#6  0x00002b4e833a58f7 in pq_begin_locked (conn=0x21f42510, pgres=0xffffffffffffffff, error=0xffffffffffffffff, tstate=0x0)
    at psycopg/pqpath.c:424
#7  0x00002b4e833a59a0 in pq_execute (curs=0x1f487528, query=0x2248c894 "SELECT 1", async=0) at psycopg/pqpath.c:764
#8  0x00002b4e833ab15b in _psyco_curs_execute (self=0x1f487528, operation=0x0, vars=0x21ec9a80, async=0)
    at psycopg/cursor_type.c:419
#9  0x00002b4e833ab7b1 in psyco_curs_execute (self=0x1f487528, args=<value optimized out>, kwargs=<value optimized out>)
    at psycopg/cursor_type.c:475
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply.

Did you use full monkey patching?

If bug still persists, please, report it via any of these ways:

- https://bitbucket.org/which_linden/eventlet/issues/new
- https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/new
- email to eventletdev@lists.secondlife.com

Please, include versions of OS, Python, Eventlet and psycopg2.